# Cosa significa "cacciarsi" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Si frugò in tasca, estrasse le due sigarette e le confrontò. Una si era tagliuzzata a metà e l’altra perdeva tabacco da un capo. Si mise tra le labbra quest’ultima, ma poi non gli riuscí di trovare la minima superficie asciutta su cui sfregare lo zolfanello. C’erano sí le guance zigrinate del calcio della Colt, ma non si sentí di farlo. Con
>   un risolino di disperazione rimise in tasca la sigaretta e **si
>   cacciò** avanti per il ciglione.

Il personaggio che svolge questa azione è Milton, il protagonista del romanzo.

Non capisco il significato di "si cacciò avanti per il ciglione" nell'ultima frase del brano. Ho letto tutte le accezioni del [verbo "cacciare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cacciare/), ma nessuna sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Direi che rientri nell'accezione del punto 4 della voce del Treccani: «Nel rifl., ficcarsi, entrar dentro o in mezzo: *cacciarsi tra la folla*; *cacciarsi in un ginepraio, nei guai, nei pasticci*; *dove s’è cacciata quella benedetta ricevuta?*», anche se parlando di un “ciglione” non è propriamente “dentro o in mezzo” a qualcosa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Cacciarsi" può essere usato nel senso di "infilarsi"/"muoversi verso".

"Si cacciò in una brutta situazione -> si infilò in una brutta situazione".

In questo caso, indica il fatto che il protagonista si incamminò in avanti per il ciglione.